# как на откатившимся коммите остаться?

Tags: git, git-commit

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда я к примеру дела команду

```
git checkout 9f77eff333089e34e4fa8536d99745af035f8a6f
```

чтоб откатиться ниже допустим на 3 комиита, и затем подумал, что я хочу на этом же коммите остаться, и делаю свои чейнджи, добавляю что-то или удаляю. Далее, делаю коммит снова, именно для этих изменений

```
git commit -m "some commit"
```

но вот когда команда

```
 git checkout branch-02 // branch-02 это текущая ветка, я не перехожу никуда
```

Меня почему-то возвращает на самый последние изменения, даже откатившийся на 3 коммита, он будто игнорирует тот коммит, который сделал после отката, то есть возвращается на самый самый последний коммит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отменить 3 коммита, надо выполнить 3 раза

```
git revert хеш-коммита
```

А потом

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько правильно, но в инете предлагают сделать так:
откатился на 3 коммита, затем сделал кое-какие  изменения, и закоммитил.
Потом командой

```
git branch -b branch-03 // создаем новую ветку
```

а затем удалил ветку branch-02

```
git branch -D branch-02
```

Потом переименовал ветку branch-03 на branch-02

```
 git branch -m branch-03 branch-02
```